# What is the difference between intellectual freedom and spiritual freedom?

Tags: freedom

What do the two, intellectual freedom and spiritual freedom, mean and how do these two differ?

Intellectual freedom is widely known but I can't seem to find reliable sources that point out the meaning of spiritual freedom.

Comment: I made an edit which you may roll back or continue editing. You can see the versions by clicking on the "edited" link above. Welcome to this SE!

Comment: what did you mean of __spiritual freedom__? could you please give more explain?

Answer (score 1):

> The United Nations upholds intellectual freedom as a basic human right through Article 19 of the Universal Declaration of Human Rights which asserts:
>
> Everyone has the right to freedom of opinion and expression; this right includes freedom to hold opinions without interference and to seek, receive and impart information and ideas through any media and regardless of frontiers.[2]

The modern concept of intellectual freedom developed out of an opposition to book censorship.[4]

It is promoted by several professions and movements. These entities include, among others, librarianship, education, and the Free Software Movement.

Intellectual freedom is often suppressed under authoritarian rule[57] and such governments often claim to have nominal intellectual freedom, although the degree of freedom is a matter of dispute.

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intellectual_freedom#Intellectual_freedom_under_authoritarian_rule

limitations on freedom of speech-

> Legal systems sometimes recognize certain limits on the freedom of speech, particularly when freedom of speech conflicts with other rights and freedoms, such as in the cases of libel, slander, pornography, obscenity, fighting words, and intellectual property. Justifications for limitations to freedom of speech often reference the "harm principle" or the "offence principle". Limitations to freedom of speech may occur through legal sanction or social disapprobation, or both.[24] Certain public institutions may also enact policies restricting the freedom of speech, for example, speech codes at state schools.

*“The highest and greatest of the human freedoms is to choose your attitude in any given set of circumstances, to choose one’s own way.”*

~ Viktor Frankl, “Man’s Search for Meaning”

The concept of Spiritual Freedom grew from Viktor Frankl’s incredible accounts of how some men triumphed emotionally and spiritually over the most horrific circumstances, Auschwitz.

“Man can preserve a vestige of spiritual freedom, of independence of mind, even in such terrible conditions of psychic and physical distress.”

Each inmate ultimately chose whether to succumb to prison camp mentality and become a mere product of their environment and experience or to try to triumph spiritually and be something more, better and different.

“*Fundamentally, therefore, any man can, even under such circumstances, decide what shall become of him – mentally and spiritually. He may retain his human dignity even in a concentration camp.”*

Therefore the two domains of freedom are in different areas of our world view-
One is sketched in intellectual activities and parallel independent processes which must be given opportunity in the human society and its various forum.

Whereas the other freedom is sketched in the human mind and a freedom to construct a subjective world view in which he can freely roam around off course coupled to the real natural world.

Comment: Just to note there are some limitations to freedom of expression: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedom_of_speech#Limitations

Comment: @Chris Degnen - thanks , a note on limitations of freedom of expression has been added.